# InfoPath 2013: Cannot generate template (SharePoint Online/Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

Using SharePoint Online/Office 365 in classic mode with InfoPath 2013. Whenever I need to edit a form template, I just usually click the `Customize in InfoPath` and it works.  Recently, I started getting the message `InfoPath cannot generate a form template for the SharePoint list`

I verified the following:

- SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features - **active**
- SharePoint Admin Center: InfoPath Settings: **browser enabled and render form templates are both checked**

I also tried opening the template via InfoPath Designer 2013, it asks for my credentials repeatedly.

Same result across all other lists in both IE and Edge. Chrome acts normally (where it usually displays a message that `IE is required to use this feature`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the above issue, refer to: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-modern-authentication-for-office-2013-on-windows-devices-7dc1c01a-090f-4971-9677-f1b192d6c910